# Having Issue on Targetting Previous Class in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/8xmakjeq/) and let me know why I am noy able to change `.num` background color dynamically using

```
$(function () {
    $('.panel-group .panel .panel-heading .panel-title > a ').on('click', function () {
        $(this).prev().closest(".num").css("background-color", "red");
    });
});
```

```js
$(function () {
    $('.panel-group .panel .panel-heading .panel-title > a ').on('click', function () {
        $(this).prev().closest(".num").css("background-color", "red");
    });

});
```

```css
.num {
    background-color: #000000;
    padding:3px 7px 3px 7px;
    color:white;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="panel-title">
<a class="c-font" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
         <span class="num">1</span> Specify Energy Target 
        </a>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.closest()` moves you upward in `DOM` to the closest parent with a specific value. You need to move downwards as per your HTML

Answer (score 1):

You need to take the child item of the link using [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
$('.panel-group .panel .panel-heading .panel-title > a ').on('click', function () {
    $(this).find(".num").css("background-color", "red");
});
```

Also your selector is way to long, simply use:

```
$('.panel-title > a ').on('click', function () {
    $(this).find(".num").css("background-color", "red");
});
```

**Working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8xmakjeq/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

Because the `.num` is the **descendant** of clicked `anchor`, use [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to select the descendent:

```
$(this).find(".num").css("background-color", "red");
```

You can also use [`children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) as `.num` is **direct descendant**:

```
$(this).children(".num").css("background-color", "red");
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/8xmakjeq/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Because `.closest()` goes up the chain, and your target `.num` is a child of the `a`.

As per https://api.jquery.com/closest/

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree

Update javascript only:

```js
$(function () {
    $('.panel-group .panel .panel-heading .panel-title > a ').on('click', function () {
        $(this).children(".num").css("background-color", "red");
    });

});
```

```css
.num {
    background-color: #000000;
    padding:3px 7px 3px 7px;
    color:white;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="panel-title">
<a class="c-font" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
         <span class="num">1</span> Specify Energy Target 
        </a>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```